# Do I need the MFC auto-created CShellManager?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have a finished application written with MFC C++ in Visual Studio 2010.  The following lines were created in my main source file.

```
// Create the shell manager, in case the dialog contains
// any shell tree view or shell list view controls.
CShellManager *pShellManager = new CShellManager;
```

I never use *pShellManager.  Is this "boiler plate" code, that is safe to comment out before a final release of my application?  Is the Shell Manager used for something that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CShellManager` wraps some Windows Shell routines to implement **Windows Explorer Tree View** that is used to display file system objects (drives, directories, files), etc. It also used for `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl::EnableFolderBrowseButton()`.
Comment it out if you don't need it.